# int accepts x as a keyword argument in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6

The following works in **Python 2.7**:

```
In [79]: int(x=5)
Out[79]: 5
```

.. but fails in **Python 3.6**:

```
In [31]: int(x=5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-53a6d75bfa9f> in <module>
----> 1 int(x=5)

TypeError: 'x' is an invalid keyword argument for int()
```

Seems like the behavior was corrected in **Python 3** to not accept `x` as a keyword argument. Can someone please confirm that my understanding is right or else correct me? Thanks.

Comment: `int` in python 3 expects only two non-keyworded arguments, which is the string and the base

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), it should only fail in Python 3.7+ ("``Changed in version 3.7: x is now a positional-only parameter.``"). I testet it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PowderblueAbsoluteDecompiler) with Python 3.6.1 and it does not throw an error. But this might be an implementation detail of your ipython installation.

Answer (score 1):

According to Python2 docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

The int signature is `class int(x=0)` or `class int(x, base=10)` which supports assigments as you observed in case of `int(x=5)

According to Python3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

The int signature is `class int([x])` or `class int(x, base=10)` where x is a variable assigned outside the function parameter, like `int('5')`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, the signature of `int()` is

```
int(x=0)
int(x, base=10)
```

In Python 3, it is nearly identical:

```
int([x])
int(x, base=10)
```

But in Python 2 it was not possible to disallow keyword arguments. In Python 3 it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the signature changed. You can compare the docs.

[`Python 3.x`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) shows this signature

```
class int([x])
class int(x, base=10)
```

But [`Python 2.x`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) shows this:

```
class int(x=0)
class int(x, base=10)
```

Notice how `3.x` does not accept keyword argument, but `2.x` does.

Answer (score 0):

In pythong 3.6 you should separate with a comma.
The syntax of int() method is: int(x=0, base=10)

You can see more in the documentation here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/int